# How to build a table's schedule with ajax and json

Tags: ajax, json

**I have this schedule in JSON this**

> schedule

:

```
[
    {
        "schedule ": {
            "startTime": "8:00 a.m.",
            "endTime": "10:00 a.m."
        },
        "classes": [
            {
                "day": "Wednesday",
                "type": "cooking",
                "instructor": "Gordon Ramsay"
            },
            {
                "day": "Monday",
                "type": "cooking",
                "instructor": "Gordon Ramsay"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "schedule ": {
            "startTime": "2:00 p.m.",
            "endTime": "4:00 p.m."
        },
        "classes": [
            {
                "day": "Tuesday",
                "type": "swimming",
                "instructor": "Lauren stuart"
            },
            {
                "day": "Friday",
                "type": "sewing",
                "instructor": "Martha steel"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**If I am accessing the first object this, just to test.**

**First , how can I do for accesing  to classes, 
And how can I to build a table for that.**

how I can go over all the classes?

```
success: function(response){
console.log(response[0].schedule.startTime)
console.log(response[0].schedule.endTime)
console.log(response[1].schedule.startTime)
console.log(response[1].schedule.endTime)
},
```

Greetings :)

Comment: Use a templating library: http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more

Comment: First think about what you want to table to look like in HTML.  Then think about how to utilize javascript to make that table structure.